# Ag-grid css problems on enterprise

Tags: angular, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm using

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^19.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^19.0.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^19.0.0"
```

But in enterprise mode I have issues with tooltip styling:
[image: left side toolbar is without style]

Without enterprise mode everything works good.
I have next html:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid  class="ag-theme-blue apartmentRep-grid"
                       [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [sideBar]="sideBar">
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

full ts file is here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zbt2ms4sG3/
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import ag-grid-comunity styles to your styles.css